# ActiveCollab API /issue-token returns warning "The session id is too long"

Tags: php, activecollab

We used to issue tokes with Paw on MacOS by sending a POST to /api/v1/issue-token, but it stopped working with one of the latest updates:

```
2017/08/11 12:08:27 [error] 29434#0: *111415 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /..../.../.../activecollab/5.13.60/angie/classes/application/AngieApplication.class.php on line 326" while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: xx.xx.xx, request: "POST /api/v1/issue-token HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/opt/php/7.0.8-pdo/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "xx.xx.xx"
```

The request contains username, password, client_name and client_vendor as JSON data.

The raw response looks like that:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 11 Aug 2017 10:08:27 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 68
Connection: close
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Angie-ApplicationVersion: 5.13.60
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN


Warning: session_start(): The session id is too long or contains il
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: ActiveCollab starts a PHP session, but does not use it for anything. In some cases with self-hosted setups, system would not work without openning a session first, so we start it even though we do not use them for anything. What I'm saying here is that we do not play with sessions in any way - is as standard as it gets (as configured in your `php.ini`). I would start by looking at the warning message, and checking what could cause the issue. Also, I would try with curl, instead of Paw, just to isolate that as a variable.